# choosing multiple persons names and then names should be separated like button if i clicked on person name that person should be deselected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to place some selected persons names in the textarea / input box, each person name will corresponds to a button if I deselect it that person 
should be removed from list

I want like this

[image]
this is actual output

[image]

**code**

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<textarea id="t"></textarea>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var str = "xyz abc abcd";
        var res = str.split(" ");
        document.getElementById("t").value = res;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: am placed a image with tags like java c html

Comment: If you are looking for a solution to implement this. Take a look at [**Select2**](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags)

Comment: Stack overflow is not a place to ask for library suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```js
$("select").select2({
  placeholder: "Select a state",
  allowClear: true
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" />

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
  <select multiple style="width:500px;">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

example:

```
https://select2.github.io/examples.html
```